# How to enable GPU while using DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator Airflow Operator?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using the `airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator` to submit jobs to GCP Dataproc from Airflow.

Now it accepts a template of the following format:

```json
{
    "placement": {
      "managed_cluster": {
        "cluster_name": ,
        "config": cluster_config
      }
    },
    "jobs": [
      {
        "step_id": task_id,
        "pyspark_job": {
          "args": [<listOfArguments>],
          "main_python_file_uri": <PythonFileToExecute>,
          "jar_file_uris": "<ListOfJarsAsAString>"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

How do I enable accelerators using this template to (say) add GPU's:

```bash
--master-accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-t4,count=2 \
--worker-accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-t4 \
```

---

Some References:

1. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataproc_cluster
2. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/ClusterConfig#GceClusterConfig
3. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/workflow-parameters#parameterizing_a_workflow_template
4. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.html#DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator

Comment: Does this [link](https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/how-do-i-enable-gpu-on-google-cloud/#:~:text=enable%20GPU%20processing.-,To%20do%20this%2C%20you%20will%20need%20to%20open%20the%20Google,on%20the%20Enable%20GPU%20button) help you in resolving the issue?